# Add a badge value in SwiftUI in a simple way for a TabView tabItem

Tags: xcode, swiftui, tabview, tabitem

Is it possible to add a badge value in SwiftUI in a simple way for a TabView tabItem?

Like this (normal Swift here) :

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.tabBar.items![2].badgeValue = "7"
}

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no property of badge count on TabViewItem in SwiftUI so you have to manually add a `ZStack` on top of TabViewItem and do some calculation.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var badgeNumber: Int = 10
  private var badgePosition: CGFloat = 1
  private var tabsCount: CGFloat = 1

  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
        // TabView
        TabView {
          Text("First View")
            .tabItem {
              Image(systemName: "tray.fill")
              Text("First")
          }
        }

        // Badge View
        ZStack {
          Circle()
            .foregroundColor(.red)

          Text("\(self.badgeNumber)")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(Font.system(size: 12))
        }
        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        .offset(x: ( ( 2 * self.badgePosition) - 1 ) * ( geometry.size.width / ( 2 * self.tabsCount ) ), y: -30)
        .opacity(self.badgeNumber == 0 ? 0 : 1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, but I'm having an issue where the badge gets pushed up when the keyboard is opened (for a TextField). The TabView stays anchored to the bottom and doesn't move, but the badge does. Any thoughts?

Comment: can you please provide me your code, I tried by adding TextField but it works fine.

Comment: To avoid moving with the keyboard (introduced with iOS14) add .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard) to the enclosing ZStack.

Comment: works, but the tab view item can no longer be tapped in place of the badge

Comment: @PeterKreinz I know it's late, you can add onTap gesture to badge zStackView